# jQuery Point A to Point B Slide effect

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jQuery Plugin, or if you can do this by some other means, thats welcome also, but anyways heres what I need to do.

On my website fsp.dbztech.com

I need the Red arrow to move from Point A (Where it is now) to Point B, down a little. on mouse over.

So it is kinda hinting at a proceed down kind of thing. If you have any other questions because this isn't enough information, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery.UI, assuming non-static (e.g. absolute) positioning of the arrow, this will move the arrow down to 400 pixels when you hover over it:

```
$(function() {
    $(".arrow").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ top: "400px" });
    });
})
```

Replacing `"400px"` with `"+=40px"` will make the arrow move 40 pixels below it's original position.